# Beamer: Top alignment of enumerations in columns

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment, itemize, columns

I want to place two item lists beside each other on the top of a slide. However the following minimal code example creates misaligned item lists at the top. How do I align them properly?

I am using pdflatex from TeX Live 2013 under Xubuntu 14.04 LTS:
"This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)"

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}
    \column{0.46\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Item xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        \end{itemize}
    \column{0.46\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Item xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        \end{itemize}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Picture of unaligned enumerations]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Sorry, but if I compile your code, the items **are** aligned in the output!

Comment: I test your MWE with MikTeX, 64-bit, with recent version of `beamer` (v 3.36), and both lines are perfectly aligned. I do not believe that between MikTeX and TeXLive is any differences in compiling of documents (it should not to be), of course if the same version of packages are used. If your version of `beamer` package is older as mine, please try to upgrade it to recent version and check again what you obtain.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by a software update as noted by the OP (with a different account) in the answers below.